# How to update listview with different data from cursor at different time

Tags: android, listview, cursor, android-cursoradapter

In my application i am firing the query to `DB` and getting back the `cursor` then i am sending that `cursor` to `Cursoradapter` to bind the data to `ListView`.
Every thing is working fine but my problem is if `cursor` has 100 to 500 rows means my `cursoradapter` is taking time to bind the data,So is there any way were i can only put 5 to 10 rows at a time to `listview` and keep on updating till all cursor values got show in list view.
Please help me..

Comment: U can make use of `expandable listview` so that ur `listview` will be updated as u scroll.

Answer (score 0):

you should use LazyLoading here is a good link for this 
http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2010/08/lazy-loading-of-images-in-list-view-in.html

Comment: thanks for suggestion but dint help me much,i want to add(bind) 5 to 10 rows at a time from the cursor and be appending the rest of the rows in a loop to the same lisview n my list view has to grow till it finish binding the all values from the cursor through Cursoradaptor.